# Writing a jQuery-like JS element selector

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write sort of jQuery-like element selecting function, to shorten regular JS element selector. So I wrote this function:

```
function _(str){
    var s = str.trim();
    var x = s.charAt(0);
    if (s.length > 0) {
        if(x == "#") return document.getElementById(s.substring(1));
        else if(x == ".") return document.getElementsByClassName(s.substring(1));
        else if(x == "*") return document.getElementsByTagName(x);
        else return document.getElementsByTagName(s);
    } else {
        return;
    }
}
```

Sample usage for that: `_("#container")`. This will return an element with `id="container"`. So far this works just fine. The problem begins when I try to pass a space as a variable (ie `_(" ")`), or an element that doesn't exist (ie `_("someelement")`) or use a wrong selector (ie `_("%p")`). Though the rest of the code still works, but if I try to do something like that...

```
var e = _("$nonexist");
e.style.backgroundColor="yellow";
```

...then in the console I'm getting the following red error message:

```
TypeError: e.style is undefined
    e.style.backgroundColor="yellow";
----^
```

So the question is: how can I prevent passing illegal characters (such as space, $, @ etc...) in parameters? If a user passes them - I just want to return a blank result and not to see these error messages in console.

Comment: What is a "blank result"? You are already returning `null`. The error is on the user's side, you cannot really prevent it. Unless you radically change your API.

Comment: I would simplify your function: `function _(str) { return document.querySelectorAll(str); }`.

Comment: @dfsq Though it doesn't solve the problem I was talking about, it does simplify the code, thanks! For some reason the ID selector (`_("#wrapper")`) didn't work as expected (return a single element with the specified ID), but returned an array, so this code `_("#wrapper")[0]` did work.

Comment: @Bergi What I meant is return something, just don't show this error. But come to think about it, the error message is actually good here, as it could indicate to user where exactly he made a mistake. I guess I should leave it as it is.

Answer (score -1):

well your code is broken then. You always return something, but it could be `undefined` if you try to access the `style` property of undefined, you will get an error because it does not exist. Depending on the type you want to return you should modify the last line of you if case. you could return '', [], undefined,etc.

```
function _(str){
    var s = str.trim();
    var x = s.charAt(0);
    if (s.length > 0) {
        if(x == "#") return document.getElementById(s.substring(1));
        else if(x == ".") return document.getElementsByClassName(s.substring(1));
        else if(x == "*") return document.getElementsByTagName(x);
        else return [];
    } else {
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: And where's the else return document.getElementsByTagName(s); ?